# Capture JSON object as single string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am posting a JSON object to asp.net mvc controller action as follows. The controller action automatically binds the json variables to individual objects. While this is a good feature, my requirement is to capture incoming json string 'as-it-is' into a single string object and store it in database. My question is how can I override the default behavior and get the the incoming json object in single string?

VIEW

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(storeLocation)IDR/OpcInsertCustomerProfile/",
            data: JSON.stringify(currSelection),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
              alert('success : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(data) {
             alert('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
          }
        );
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("OpcInsertCustomerProfile")]
        public JsonResult OpcInsertCustomerProfile(string jsonProfile)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return Json(jsonProfile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return Json(new { error = 1, message = exc.Message });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HttpRequest` object, there is a forms variable collection you can get the raw data from that object.

```
string rawdata = Request.Form["variable name"];
```

You have to find the variable name.

You can use the debugger to see this.

Comment: Thanks, however I need raw JSON string to be stored in DB for future retrieval.

Comment: You can get the raw string from form collection, then store it in data base. from raw string i mean " { "surname": "Aaberg", "phone": [ "555-0100", "555-0120" ] }"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this
Converting your content back to json

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
     new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);


[{"Name":"Pini","Age":"30","ID":"111"},
{"Name":"Yaniv","Age":"31","ID":"Cohen"},
{"Name":"Yoni","Age":"20","ID":"Biton"}]
```

[Reference Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx)